# Swift 3 and Shell command with non regular arguments

Tags: ios, swift, bash, shell, cocoa

When I calling through terminal

```
(echo authenticate '""'; echo signal newnym; echo quit) | /usr/bin/nc localhost 9051
```

it works fine. But I need to use it via swift. How to write that to put in arguments?

*P.S. I was searching a lot of shell syntax and using shell in the swift/objc... But still can nothing to do with that...*

That's my shell function:

```
func shell(_ path: String = "/bin/bash", arguments: [String] = [], waitUntilExit: Bool = false) -> String {

    let task        = Process()
    task.launchPath = path
    task.arguments  = arguments

    let pipe = Pipe()
    task.standardOutput = pipe
    task.launch()

    let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()

    if waitUntilExit {

        task.waitUntilExit()

    }

    return String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!

}
```

calling

```
self.shell(arguments: ["(echo authenticate '""'; echo signal newnym; echo quit) | /usr/bin/nc localhost 9051"])
```

output is

```
No such file or directory (echo authenticate '""'; echo signal newnym; echo quit)
```

Swift thinks `(` is a directory. Why?

Comment: You are trying to do the equivalent of `bash "(echo ..) | /usr/bin/nc localhost 9051"`; `bash` is treating the first (and only) argument as the name of a script to execute. You need to either use `bash -c "(echo ...) | ..."`, or feed the string to `bash'` standard input.

Comment: @chepner, thanks alot! `self.shell(arguments: ["-c", "(echo authenticate '\"\"'; echo signal newnym; echo quit) | /usr/bin/nc localhost 9051"])` works! Please, tell me, what -c flag does?

Comment: It specifies a string the shell should use to execute a command, instead of reading from standard input or a file argument.

Comment: @osadchi To find out what option arguments do to any command, read its documentation. You'll never be a decent programmer if you don't learn to read manuals.

Comment: @Barmar, I thought only practice can make me stronger xD.